# Use Sharepoint 2013 as Email client

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, email

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 Foundation and I would know if is it possible to use SP as email client at least to show emails from a selected inbox.

Thanks

Comment: It is possible to send Emails to the sharepoint list. But a inbox representation is in foundation not possible.

Answer (score 1):

They dropped this support in the latest release of SharePoint - there used to be a web part o let you do exactly what you want: http://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/integrating-outlook-web-access-owa-and-sharepoint-2013/